# Chrome - Disable autocomplete only on selected websites

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autocomplete

Is there a way to disable the input autocomplete in chrome, but only on several pages/website ?

Example with PhpMyAdmin, I don't want autocomplete, whatever the input :

[image]

But I want for other websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your manifest file, configure [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) to match the website urls that you want your extension work out
2. In your content scripts, try to get the input field by selectors then set the [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) attribute off